# Working with Join for Latest row aaded of each master table row?

Tags: mysql

These are my two tables, `Leadid` is Primary Key.

Table1 - (Master)

```
Leadid  Customer Name
101     Ramesh Kumar
102     Rajan Kumar
103     Rahul Kumar
```

Table2 - (Transaction)

```
id  Leadid  Followed_by
1   101     SAKSHI
2   101     MADHURI
3   101     SAKSHI
4   102     SAKSHI
5   102     MADHURI
6   103     SAKSHI
7   103     SAKSHI
```

Question : I need a common query where i will change only FOllower Name and

IN CASE OF MADHURI RESULT SHOULD BE:

```
102        Rajan Kumar     5   102     MADHURI
```

IN CASE OF SAKSHI RESULT SHOULD BE:

```
101     Ramesh Kumar      3     101     SAKSHI
103     Rahul Kumar       7     103     SAKSHI
```

if same lead id is followed by others, previous transcation should not be included...

i e Leadid 101 was followed by madhuri also but then after followed by SAKSHI.

so it should not be displayed when putting query for MADHURI.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4fbb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NOT EXISTS() to achieve this results, like this:

```
SELECT s.*,t.* FROM Table1 s
INNER JOIN Transaction t
 ON(t.leadid = s.leadid)
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Transaction tt
                 WHERE t.leadid = tt.leadid
                   AND t.id < tt.id)
 AND t.followed_by = 'SAKASHI'
```

If you want someone else, change SAKASHI to what you want.

Comment: Thanks @sagi ....Yes Adjectly same but if query i am looking for user wise.. if i send query for SAKSHI only SAKSHI Leads should be.

Comment: above code gives result for all follower i want seperate for SAKSHI & MADHURI.

Comment: I edited the question as I already told you. It will now take only SAKASHI , and if you want change it to MADHURI @RanjanKumar

Comment: Thanks , My Problem Solved.. If you have time then Can you please explain me how it is working